# Open Edx Error during Install

Tags: mysql, azure, openedx

I'm trying to install the production stack on my azure cloud (VM) but I'm getting the following Error:

```
TASK: [edxlocal | install mysql 56 and dependencies] **************************
failed: [localhost] => (item=software-properties-common,mysql-server) => {"failed": true, "item": "software-properties-common,mysql-server"}
stderr: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

stdout: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.6 but it is not going to be installed

msg: '/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef" -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold" --force-yes  install 'mysql-server'' failed: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
       to retry, use: --limit @/root/edx_sandbox.retry

localhost                  : ok=43   changed=6    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

do "sudo su -" before installing, and It will be installed success